# How to access elements in Vector of Vectors

Tags: multidimensional-array, vector, reference, scheme

```
(set! max-vector        9)

(set! procedures-vector (vector (vector 0 0 0)
                                (vector 1 1 1)
                                (vector 2 4 2)
                                (vector 3 9 4)
                                (vector 4 16 8)
                                (vector 5 25 12)
                                (vector 6 36 18)
                                (vector 7 49 24)
                                (vector 8 64 32)))

(set! drawables-index 0)
(while (< drawables-index max-vector)       
       (set! vector-element (vector-ref procedures-vector drawables-index))
       (set! element-length (vector-length vector-element))

       (set! vector-element-a (vector-ref vector-element 0))
       (set! vector-element-b (vector-ref vector-element 1))
       (set! vector-element-c (vector-ref vector-element 2))

       (set! drawables-index (+ drawables-index 1)))
```

The problem is that in each iteration the vector-elements a,b & c are
the same ! So I see (0 0 0) fair enough and (1 1 1) - OK that's cool but
it goes on to produce (2 2 2) (3 3 3). I verified the element length of 
the vector-ref results on the procedures-vector and It retured 3 
( correct ! 3 elements, in each element of the vector list ).

Ok I am foxed. Would some wise soul please look at this and see if I 
could be helped. Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more in detail an structured? At the moment its rather unclear..

Answer (score 1):

You access vectors in vectors with nested vector-ref:

```scm
(vector-ref (vector-ref vector row) column)
```

You alter data with `vector-set!`-ing the nested vector:

```scm
(vector-set! (vector-ref vector row) column value)
```

Since you do it 3 times you can do the selecting of row vector as a temporary variable:

```scm
(let ((rowv (vector-ref vector row)))
  (let ((a (vector-ref rowv 0)) ...)
    (vector-set! rowv 0 (+ a 1)) ...))
```

`set!` alters what variable names point at. They never change the actual object it pointed to.